# Difference between client.indices.putTemplate and client.putTemplate

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

What is the difference between [client.indices.putTemplate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-puttemplate) and [client.putTemplate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-puttemplate) using the Javascript ElasticSearch Client, [Elasticsearch.js](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-2.html#api-searchtemplate-2-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.indices.putTemplate` is to create [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)...

...while `client.putTemplate` is to create [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html).

If you follow the links given in the JS API documentation under the respective method, you'll land on the same links I shared above.